# INSERT value into next NULL in a column

Tags: sql-server, database

Each time I upload a file path to a database, the string is being saved on the next row in the database as you would expect (See attached image). But I want to save it in the next null row of the individual column, ignoring that other columns may have more values.

I have tried variations using `for` `where` and `if`.

**NOTE:** I am creating a column for each user so as not to limit the number of file paths to 1024.

**NOTE2:** This question may be unnecessary as I read that `"...if you have more than 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 rows you would run into problems...(maximum size of a bigint) – Martin Smith"` but I still dont like the idea of wasting all those rows, if only to ease readability in server management studio and server object explorer.

Any ideas how to avoid this?

Create column with users unique account number:

```
oSqlCommand.CommandText = "IF COL_LENGTH('User_Images','" + AcNo.Text + "') IS NULL BEGIN ALTER TABLE User_Images ADD [" + AcNo.Text + "] char(200) null END";
```

Insert saved file path into users column:

```
oSqlCommand1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO User_Images([" + AcNo.Text + "]) VALUES ('https://xxxx.xxxx.core.windows.net/container-" + AcNo.Text + "/" + fileName + "');";
```

In the image below I uploaded two files logged in as user 1, then I uploaded two files logged in as user 2, then one file logged in as user 8. The NULL values in Rows 1-4 for user 2 and user 8 are a terrible waste of space.

[image]

Comment: Wasted null values should be less of a concern than having a column per user. If you end up with 20.000 users your table will have 20.000 columns? Why can't you use an images table with columns UserId, ImagePath?

Comment: Sorry to break it to you but your data model is very, very wrong!  You need more rows and fewer columns (and an additional table or two no doubt).

Comment: You need to change your table schema to have only 3 columns: `UploadId, UserId, FilePath`, where `UploadId` would be an auto-incrementing primary key. Also, you will need to change your INSERT query to this: `"INSERT INTO User_Images([UserId], [FilePath]) VALUES (" 
+ AcNo.Text + ",'https://xxxx.xxxx.core.windows.net/container-" + AcNo.Text + "/" + fileName + "');"`

Comment: If you follow the above approach there would zero wasted space in the the form of null values, plus your table would be normalized according to database design best practice.

Comment: So then when I want to recall all the images stored by an individual user_id I will search the column and pull out the paths beside each instance of the users id, yes? (Instead of just taking all values from a column as now) @artm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database table is not normalized at all. So the answer to your question of not wasting rows with many null values is to normalize your table design.

You need to change your table schema to have only 3 columns: `UploadId, UserId, FilePath`, where `UploadId` would be an auto-incrementing primary key. Also, you will need to change your INSERT query to as below. **With this design there is no limit on how many uploads a user can do plus there is zero wasted space.**
`UserId` is same as `AcNo`, so you change this column name if you want to.

*You would not need the first query where  you are using `ALTER TABLE` to insert a new column into your original table every time a user uploads for the first time.*

**New INSERT query**

```
   oSqlCommand1.CommandText =  "INSERT INTO User_Images([UserId], [FilePath]) VALUES (" + AcNo.Text + ",'https://xxxx.xxxx.core.windows.net/container-" + AcNo.Text + "/" + fileName + "');"
```

If you think you might have a huge number of uploads done by users, then use `bigint` for `UploadId` data type, else use int. I have used `bigint` so you are saved from overflow error if there are too many uploads done by users.

**Table Creation Script**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.User_Images
(
 UploadId bigint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 UserId  bigint,
 FilePath  varchar(5000)
)
```

Comment: So then when I want to recall all the images stored by an individual user_id I will search the column and pull out the paths beside each instance of the users id, yes? (Instead of just taking all values from a column as now) @Sunil

Comment: @DMur, Yes, that is correct. `SELECT FilePath from dbo.User_Images  where UserId = 4` will give you all uploads by a user having userid of 4.

Comment: @DMur, You can even add a column to capture when upload was done by adding a column `UploadDate DATETIME` to the CREATE TABLE query.